# Retrieve table in database to phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am using php excel export the data in database to Excel format.
I can retrieve all the data from database to Excel ady. But if i wanna to retrieve the column name of the table, how i going to do. Anyone can help?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

   header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=product.xls");
    header("Pragma:no-cache");
    header("Expires:0");

  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        header("Content-type: application/octetstream");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
 /** Error reporting */
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

  if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

 /** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
 require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
  require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';  

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
  if (!$con) 
  { 
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
 } 

 mysql_select_db("litako", $con); 



   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vendorlist ");

  /** Error reporting */
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');



  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

 if(!$res){
die("Error");
 }


 $col = 0; 
 $row = 3; 
 while($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
$col = 0; 
 foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); 
    $col++; 
} 
$row++; 
 }
  // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  // Save Excel 2007 file
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="report.xls"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
  // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
 header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
 header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
  header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');


 exit;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the column name in your while loop where you call mysql_fetch_assoc. The $key value is the column name. So here is an updated portion of your code:

```
 while($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    $col = 0; 
    foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
        // TODO: Do Something With the Column Name like set the row header. Note this crude code sets it every time. You really just want to do it the first time only.
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 0, $key);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row + 1, $value); 
        $col++; 
    } 
    $row++; 
 }
```

Comment: Whenever you call mysql_fetch_assoc it returns an array where the array keys are the column names and the array values are the column values. In your foreach call you are telling PHP to assign the column name to the variable called $key when you do *$mrow as $key=>$value*. You could just as easily assign it to another variable like $columnName by doing: *$mrow as $columnName=>$columnValue*.